# how to match one variable in row and return value than another condition which return another row in r code

Tags: r, pattern-matching

i) I want to match file1 column is equal to "CL" then return CL row and immediate "NQ" row should be returned if file1 column is equal to "NQ" and file2 column equal to "IL"  form as table

```
                file1  file2 file3 file4    
                 NQ      85    1      S 
                 NQ      IL    1      S 
                 NQ      PR    2      A     
                 CL      49    60     J    
                 NQ      IL    1      K 
                 DM      D8    9      F 
                 NQ      PR    2      N   
                 CL      21    4      3         
                 HI      B     5      1 
                 NQ      IL   11     10   
                 3       8     2     11
                 CL      2     8     18   
                 REF     X     9     19

 This data is in data table format.please help me to achieve the expected table.
 file1 file2 file3 file4 
  NQ    IL   1     S    
  CL    49   60    J   
  NQ    IL   1     K    
  CL    21   4     3    
  NQ    IL   11    10   
  CL    2    8     18
```

Comment: I do not understand your matching criteria.

Comment: It is like reverse iteration, where my first condition is file1=="CL" and then the second condition is to check for file1== "NQ" in file1 again then the third condition should be on the file2=="IL" - if all matches and return the expected table.

Comment: Where does the `S` in row 1 column 3 in your second table come from?

Comment: that was by mistake, I have edited. I apologise

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subset`

```
subset(df, file1 == 'NQ' & file2 == 'IL' | file1 == 'CL')
#file1 file2 file3 file4
#   NQ    IL     1     S
#   CL    49    60     J
#   NQ    IL     1     K
#   CL    21     4     3
#   NQ    IL    11    10
#   CL     2     8    18
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "file1  file2 file3 file4    
NQ      85    1      S 
NQ      IL    1      S 
NQ      PR    2      A     
CL      49    60     J    
NQ      IL    1      K 
DM      D8    9      F 
NQ      PR    2      N   
CL      21    4      3         
HI      B     5      1 
NQ      IL   11     10   
3       8     2     11
CL      2     8     18   
REF     X     9     19", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Glad I could help. You might consider to accept the answer.

Comment: They say I have to get 15 reputations to show my opinion on screen but marks will be counted internally